# Trying to parse access.log

Tags: json, python-3.x, parsing, argparse

Good afternoon, I'm trying to find the top 10 ip in access.log (standard log of the Apache server).
There is a code like this:

```
import argparse
import json
import re
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='parser script')
parser.add_argument('-f', dest='logfile', action='store', default='access.log')
args = parser.parse_args()

regul_ip = (r"^(?P<ips>.*?)")
regul_method = (r"\"(?P<request_method>GET|POST|PUT|DELETE|HEAD)")

def req_by_method():
    dict_ip = defaultdict(lambda: {"GET": 0, "POST": 0, "PUT": 0, "DELETE": 0, "HEAD": 0})
    with open(args.logfile) as file:
     for index, line in enumerate(file.readlines()):
        try:
              ip = re.search(regul_ip, line).group()
              method = re.search(regul_method, line).groups()[0]
              return Counter(dict_ip).most_common(10)
        except AttributeError:
             pass
        dict_ip[ip][method] += 1

print(json.dumps(dict_ip, indent=4))
with open("final_log.json", "w") as jsonfile:
    json.dump(dict_ip, jsonfile, indent=5)
```

When the code is executed, I only get:  []
How can I fix this code to make it work?

I also need to output to the final json file a set of such lines: "ip", "method", "status code", "url" and the duration of the request

Comment: Can you share some examples of the log file your trying to parse?

Comment: Sure. This is a line from a file: 109.169.248.247 - - [12/Dec/2015:18:25:11 +0100] "GET /administrator/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" 7269

Comment: you could get the IP and METHOD in the same regex, see https://regex101.com/r/WQQm20/1

Comment: Yes, but my code still isn't working

Comment: Can you please edit your question to clarify whether you a. are "trying to find the top 10 ip in access.log", b. create a json file with "a set of such lines: "ip", "method", "status code", "url" and the duration of the request", or c. a combination of a. and b. (and if that is the case, what that combination is)? If you're looking for a variation of b., can you add a sample log line in your question and show which fields you need? It is an Apache access log, yes, but the format can vary (see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_log_config.html).